# grep with limited recursion when redirect file exists

Tags: search, grep, redirect

I'd like to search a word in all files under a directory recursively, and output the occurrence lines into an output file in the directory.

`grep -ri "my_str" ./ >> opt_file.txt`

However, since "my_str" also appears in opt_file.txt, the occurrence in opt_file.txt is also recursively listed in the redirected file and hence forms an infinite loop. Is there any simple way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`man grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/grep.1.html):

```
--exclude=GLOB
      Skip  files  whose  base  name  matches  GLOB  (using   wildcard
      matching).   A  file-name  glob  can  use  *,  ?,  and [...]  as
      wildcards, and \ to quote  a  wildcard  or  backslash  character
      literally.
```

Therefore:

```
grep -ri "my_str" ./ >> opt_file.txt --exclude=opt_file.txt
```

Though I'd just keep the file elsewhere to avoid complications where a similar file also exists in a subdirectory:

```
grep -ri "my_str" ./ >> ../opt_file.txt
grep -ri "my_str" ./ >> /tmp/opt_file.txt
```